# Can not show images on harbor

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, harbor

I installed harbor through helm-harbor which version is v1.1.0.

My problem is that I can `docker login` succeed on terminal, and successfully `docker push` images, but after that there is no image showing in harbor web page, there is no any image there.

I checked the log of the container registry of pod harbor-registry which constantly generate the following information, I don't know if this has some relationship with my problem.

```
10.244.3.1 - - [05/Jul/2019:16:52:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "" "kube-probe/1.12"
10.244.3.1 - - [05/Jul/2019:16:52:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "" "kube-probe/1.12"
time="2019-07-05T16:52:15.959957799Z" level=info msg="response completed" go.version=go1.11.8 http.request.host="telling-hydra-harbor-registry:5000" http.request.id=4e553265-0dcc-4e8d-86fe-80f76bfc1a1d http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="10.244.3.193:57186" http.request.uri="/v2" http.request.useragent="Go-http-client/1.1" http.response.contenttype="text/html; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration="276.091µs" http.response.status=301 http.response.written=39
10.244.3.193 - - [05/Jul/2019:16:52:15 +0000] "GET /v2 HTTP/1.1" 301 39 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"
time="2019-07-05T16:52:15.963158432Z" level=debug msg="authorizing request" go.version=go1.11.8 http.request.host="telling-hydra-harbor-registry:5000" http.request.id=3e6c1e3e-f26a-411f-bd53-05a5bedfe562 http.request.method=GET http.request.referer="http://telling-hydra-harbor-registry:5000/v2" http.request.remoteaddr="10.244.3.193:57186" http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="Go-http-client/1.1"
10.244.3.193 - - [05/Jul/2019:16:52:15 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 "http://telling-hydra-harbor-registry:5000/v2" "Go-http-client/1.1"
time="2019-07-05T16:52:15.963272246Z" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: authorization token required" go.version=go1.11.8 http.request.host="telling-hydra-harbor-registry:5000" http.request.id=3e6c1e3e-f26a-411f-bd53-05a5bedfe562 http.request.method=GET http.request.referer="http://telling-hydra-harbor-registry:5000/v2" http.request.remoteaddr="10.244.3.193:57186" http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="Go-http-client/1.1"
```

Is there any one can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating /etc/docker/daemon.json file and adding the below content and then doing a docker restart on CentOS 7 and  ubuntu resolved the issue.

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "Docker_registery_IP:5000" ]
}
```

Comment: I checked `values.yaml`, there is no port 5000 in there, and `telnet Docker_registery_IP:5000 `, and the port is not accessible.  I `docker login` using port 80, and I found nginx is listening 80 port, and push successfully. So how can i change the configuration? thanks

Comment: so add port 80 instead of 5000

Comment: "insecure-registries" : [ "Docker_registery_IP:80"]

Comment: But we got the original problem, harbor does now show images on web page...

Comment: I already have add  [ "Docker_registery_IP:80"] to "insecure-registries", and this is the original problem